# how to correctly apply the foldr function

Tags: haskell, syntax, fold

Im attempting to find the max element of a list, where the elements are a data type created by myself, using a fold instead of doing it recursively. However i  end up with an error "couldn't match type". As im fairly new to haskell im having trouble seeing the problem and wish to know how to correctly apply the foldr function.

My attempt at obtaining the largest elements looks like this:

-- (foldr comparison (head list) (tail list))

which won't compile.

i have included the datatype and its instances for Eq and Ord, and i've also included the comparison function.

```
 -- Car data type

 data Car = Car {registration :: String,
                    hour :: Integer, 
                  minute :: Integer, 
               tupleForm :: PTime
           }

-- Equality comparison between Car data types
-- reqiures equality by registration number, hours and minutes

instance Eq Car where 
     (Car r1 h1 m1 _) == (Car r2 h2 m2 _) = (r1 == r2) && (((h1*60)+m1) == 
((h2*60)+m2))

-- Order comparison between Car data types
-- Compares time of two Cars , hours and minutes 

instance Ord Car where 
     compare (Car _ h1 m1 _) (Car _ h2 m2 _) = compare ((h1*60)+m1) 
     ((h2*60)+m2)  


-- Returns the larger Car
comparison :: (Car,Car) -> Car
comparison(car1,car2) = if(car1 > car2) then car1 else car2
```

My expected result after folding the list of Car is to obtain the 'largest car' ,which basically means the car with the largest time. But I end up with a compilation error due to faulty type.

Comment: Once you've made a type an instance of `Ord`, as you have here, you get a `maximum` function "for free". So you don't need to implement your own. (If you want to for practice, you should probably use `foldr1` rather than just `foldr`, because it doesn't make a lot of sense to find the maximum of an empty list).

Comment: did not think about the maximum function, how nice! I'll use it instead of folding, but i'll leave the question up for future references on how to fold something like this correctly seeing how im unable to figure out what whent wrong. 
@RobinZigmond much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the type and definition of `comparison`.

First, the type should be `Car -> Car -> Car`: you take *two* `Car` values and return the bigger one.

Second, your definition of `comparison` tries to match a *single* argument as a tuple, rather than two separate arguments. Drop the parentheses and the comma.

```
comparison :: Car -> Car -> Car
comparison car1 car2 = if car1 > car2 then car1 else car2
```

(Of course, `comparison` is just `max` restricted to `Car` rather than `Ord a => a`.

```
comparison :: Car -> Car -> Car
comparison = max
```

And, as Robin Zigmond points out, `foldr comparison x` is basically `maximum` for an appropriate value `x`.)

Comment: i mustve uploaded the wrong version of comparison because i originally passed a pair of Car as argument. But seeing your answer i understand that it wasn't a tuple pair it wanted. thx!

Comment: You could define `comparison' :: (Car, Car) -> Car`, `comparison' (car1, car2) = <same definition as before>`, but that's not idiomatic. (However, the two are isomorphic, as `comparison == curry comparison'` and `comparison' == uncurry comparison`.)

Comment: just to clarify - I was referring to `maximum` in reference to what it seemed the OP was trying to implement with the `foldr`, to get the maximum of a list according to the defined ordering. Of course you're right to point out that the `comparison` shown here is just `uncurry max`

Comment: Ah, OK. I assumed you made the same mistake I usually make, which is to confuse which of `maximum` and `max` takes a list (er, `Foldable`) and which takes two explicit values. :)

Comment: @RobinZigmond I've edited my answer to try to put more accurate words in your mouth :)

Comment: @chepner - oh, I often do confuse them, but I did look up the `maximum` function before typing that, to check that I'd got the right one (as well as that it automatically worked on any instance of `Ord`)

Answer (score 1):

Consider the simplified type of `foldr`.

```hs
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
```

This is a lot more general than you require because you’re dealing with all Cars. That means to find the biggest `Car` with `foldr`, the type becomes

```hs
foldr :: (Car -> Car -> Car) -> Car -> [Car] -> Car
```

The first argument is a function that selects between two Cars. In your case, you want `max` because its type

```hs
max :: Ord a => a -> a -> a
```

becomes

```hs
max :: Car -> Car -> Car
```

and matches exactly.

The second argument to `foldr` is named `z` for zero. It is the seed for the folding process. For this, you may as well use the first element of your list, obtained with `head`.

The list argument of type `[Car]` is obviously the list whose maximum you want to compute. You could pass the entire list, but the head is already accounted for as the `z` argument. Better would be `tail list`.

Given the following list (after modifying `Car` to remove `tupleForm` and derive a `Show` instance)

```hs
cars = [ Car "A" 1 2, Car "B" 3 4, Car "C" 10 10 ]
```

finding the maximum with `foldr` is

```hs
λ> foldr max (head cars) (tail cars)
Car {registration = "C", hour = 10, minute = 10}
```

Note that this application of `foldr` is equivalent to `maximum`, but you don’t have to take my word for it. Adding

```hs
import Test.QuickCheck
```

to the top of your source file and then

```hs
prop_max :: [Car] -> Property
prop_max l =
  not (null l) ==>
    maximum l == foldr max (head l) (tail l)

instance Arbitrary Car where
  arbitrary = do
    r <- oneof $ map return ["Apple","Orange","Banana"]
    h <- choose (0,23)
    m <- choose (0,59)
    return (Car r h m)
```

gives more confidence in the assertion.

```hs
λ> quickCheck prop_max
+++ OK, passed 100 tests.
```